# BootstrapTable dont load data

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

If i load data from ajax call this way once, data is loaded fine into the table :

```
$.ajax({
        url: actionUrl,
        data: {LanguageUid : test, SystemUid : test},
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true
    }).success(function (data) {
        $('#MainTable').bootstrapTable({
            data: data.items
        });
    });
```

However if i try to reload every time i call to the same ajax call this way :

```
$('#MainTable').bootstrapTable('load', {data :  data.items } );
```

nothing is loaded. Data.items are the same. Any idead what i have done wrong?

Comment: You mean the items loaded are always the same? Or they are different, but remain the same in the table?

Comment: I mean they dont load at all if use second method.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced with the same problem. I solve it by putting the **data-toggle="table"** attribute to table.

```
<table id="MainTable" data-toggle="table">
</table>
```

Then, calling in this way works in my case.

```
$('#MainTable').bootstrapTable('load', {data :  data.items } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#MainTable').bootstrapTable('destroy')`before resending your ajax call.

I think it is a bad pattern in the bootstrapTable function design.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.
but, below code solve issue.
 `$('#tblData').bootstrapTable('destroy');`

BTW, i still does not know the reason.